# Using taghelpers for a different model within a form than the View expects

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, tag-helpers

I have a view that is expecting a `@model` of type `Foo`.

However, within the page I have a form that I want to submit to a different action, which expects a different model of type `Bar`.

The reason I'm doing this is because the view I have is showing details about the object `Foo`, but the form that's submitted is collecting information not related to `Foo` at all. And I don't want to combine the properties of the two models.

Using asp taghelpers seems to depend on the aforementioned `@model` at the top of the View, which is fine. But is there a way to continue using them, but bind them to a different type in the context of a form, perhaps?

Answer (score -1):

Put your form in a separate view with it's own model and render it into your main view via `@Html.RenderAction()`

Comment: I don't think that particular assembly is available in ASP5/MVC6. Can't find it, based on msdn docs, but I think I can render a partial, pass in a model that way and see how that works.

Comment: It's possible, I didn't have the chance to use the new framework yet. It seems to have been replace by ViewComponent https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/mvc/views/view-components.html